# Loading csv data into D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am using the following code to transform csv data into flare.json. Can some one explain what wrong am i doing? When I visualize the data, I will get jsut a single node (circle), with no links or other nodes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

    <style>

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

.node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }   
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the external data
d3.csv("data/csvData.csv", function(error, data) {

// *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
// create a name: node map
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.name] = node;
    return map;
}, {});

// create the tree array
var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
    // add to parent
    var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
    if (parent) {
        // create child array if it doesn't exist
        (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
            // add node to child array
            .push(node);
console.log("adding child:" + node.name + " to parent:" + parent.name);

    } else {
        // parent is null or missing
        treeData.push(node);
console.log("adding root:" + node.name);        
    }
});

  var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; }); 
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

/*  ------------------ */
/*  addtional funtions */
/*  ------------------ */
function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
//here's the csv data
parent,children
"", "root"
"root","parent1"
"root","parent2"
"root","parent3"
"parent1","child1"
"parent2","child2"
"parent2","child3"
"parent3","child4"
```

Comment: Your code is only loading data into memory.  There is no rendering code.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis - please see the complete code.

Comment: I think @GeorgeHoupis is right, after seeing your complete code. You fail to render data, because d3.csv is asynchronous function. Please make sure 'dataMap' is not empty, just after calling d3.csv.